# default paramater value in class python

Tags: python, class, parameters

i have two class. first class is RegularPolygon and second is child class inheritance from RegularClass. I want to set default value in number of side = 4. I have try (which is i put comment on this code) but the result is "**non-default argument follows default argument python class...**"

```
class RegularPolygon:
    def __init__(self, no_of_sides, side_length):
        self.no_of_sides = no_of_sides
        self.side_length = side_length
    def perimeter(self):
        keliling_poligon = self.no_of_sides * self.side_length
        return keliling_poligon
    def interior_angle(self):
        int_angle = (self.no_of_sides - 2) * 180/self.no_of_sides
        return int_angle
    def exterior_angle(self):
        _=360/self.no_of_sides
        return ext_angle
    
class Square(RegularPolygon):
    def __init__(self, no_of_sides, side_length):
        super().__init__(no_of_sides, side_length)
        self.no_of_sides = 4
    def area(self):
        area_square = self.side_length**2
        return area_square
    def diagonal(self):
        diagonal_square = self.side_length*(2**0.5)
        return diagonal_square

square_1 = Square(5)

s_perim = square_1.perimeter()
s_area = square_1.area()
angl_int = square_1.interior_angle()
angl_ext = square_1.exterior_angle()
diagonal = square_1.diagonal()

result = (s_perim, s_area, angl_int, angl_ext, diagonal)
print(result)
```

i want put default value 4 in child class Square
and then produce error

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-cdd5b6433650> in <module>
     29         return diagonal_square
     30 
---> 31 bujursangkar = Square(5)
     32 
     33 keliling = bujursangkar.perimeter()

TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'side_length'
```

Comment: If you want default value, then try - `def __init__(self, no_of_sides = 4, side_length):`

Comment: @PCM, this will produce exactly the error OP complains about.

Comment: @PCM - I believe your suggestion will lead to the same error message.

Comment: The error message is quite clear - it is telling you to change your function signature from `f(x=4, y, z)` to `f(y, z, x=4)`

Comment: Arguments with default values must be specified after the required arguments so you would need to have `def __init__(self,side_length, no_of_sides = 4):` or set a default value also to `side_length`

Comment: @PCM in child class Square

Answer (score 0):

As you have two variables defined `def __init__(self, no_of_sides, side_length):` you should use `square_1 = Square(4,5)` instead of `square_1 = Square(5)`.

You can also use the following instead:

```
class Square(RegularPolygon):
    def __init__(self, side_length, no_of_sides = 4):
        super().__init__(no_of_sides, side_length)
    def area(self):
        # ... code ...
```

In the latter case you can if you want override the value for `no_of_sides`  whenever is needed.